# twig thumbnail - set relative offset

Tags: twig, octobercms, twig-filter

I'm using OctoberCMS and my thumbnail gallery is generated this way:

```
<img src="{{ image.thumb(250, 250, {mode:'crop', offset: [0,100]} ) }}">
```

The offset value will "overshoot" the picture, if the picture format is 1:1.

I'm looking for a way to get the very top of every image size, like the css property

```
background-position: 0% 0%;
```

Do you have any ideas?

Here's a picture, where you can see that twig "overshoots" in the top row:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d88K3.jpg)

Comment: Please show your thumbnail gallery image so we can help you.

Comment: I included a picture

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can use **`background-image`** property of **CSS** and with `background-image` property you can use `background-position` property.
For `background-position` property, you have more options [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

> **Note**: For using `backgrond-image` property you have to use **auto** mode in thumbnail generator function.

If you have defined any `link` on that image you can use `background-image` property on the link and give inline CSS on it, like below

```
<a href="your_url" 
style="background-position: center top; background-image: url({{image.getThumb(250, 250, 'auto')}})">
</a>
```

or Instead of **`<a>`** tag, You can use any HTML tags like **`<div>`**  and give CSS Properties(particular **height** and **width**) for that **`<div>`** and manage your view.

Try this, and tell me your reviews.

Comment: works perfect! thank you very much! - I used a div with the style "width: 100%; padding-bottom:100%;max-width:250px;max-height:250px;" to get the square shape.